# How to move directories in Ranger?

Tags: linux, fedora, file-transfer, file-management, ranger

I'm using [Ranger](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ranger) file manager.

I want to move selected (`mark`ed) directories to the path provided.

[image: Example image]

I've been moving directories using `dd` and `pp` but it requires the user to go to the destination directory to "paste" them into.

There's a undocumented `move` command which I don't know how to use.

And I also guess it may be done through external shell command somehow, but I want to do it natively through the `move` command.

Comment: You can move directories with the same shell command you normally use to move directories. Within Ranger, just enter  !  and then type your shell command.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like more to do it natively given that `move` command is available and as it would be easier I think.

Answer (score 12):

I never needed ranger's native `move` command with being able to use the `mv` command on the ranger command line, to move the selected file or directory to a given directory, e.g.:

```
shell -f mv %f /foo/bar
```

where `%f` is the ranger macro for highlighted files, and `%s` would be for all the selected.

The option `-f` forks the operation so that the ranger session is not interrupted by a long file process.

You can summon the comand line with s, ! or @.

Another way, especially if you have many copies/moves to make, is to open another tab in ranger, with `gn` and cd to the directory you want to copy/move the files to.  Then return to the first tab to select files and use the ranger macro for the next tab `%D`, to move files to, like,

```
shell -f mv %f %D
```

But that actually only saves you from hitting `yy Tab dd Tab`. To be honest I usually switch tab and `dd`.

I set up key-bindings in the rc.conf file like so,

```
#sync sel'd into dir on next tab
map ytt shell -f rsync -rult %s %D      

#sync sel'd from dir on next tab
map yff shell -f rsync -rult %S %d      

#sync sel'd into dir on next tab  :incl referred files
map ytr shell -f rsync -ruLt %s %D      

#sync sel'd from dir on next tab  :incl referred files
map yfr shell -f rsync -ruLt %S %d      

#move sel'd into dir on next tab
map dtt shell -f mv %s %D      

#move sel'd from dir on next tab
map dff shell -f mv %S %d
```

Note that `%S` is the macro for the selected files on the next tab.
`%d` is the macro for the directory path of current tab.

And some others,

```
#copy sel'd into h'd dir
map pc shell -f rsync -rut %s %d/%f/  

#move sel'd into h'd dir
map pm shell -f mv -u %s %d/%f  

#copy buffer into h'd dir
map pds shell -f rsync -rult %c %d/%f/       

#move buffer into h'd dir
map pdm shell -f mv -u %c %d/%f              

#sync buffer'd files into curr dir :links only
map ps shell -f rsync -rult %c %d
```

Where `%c` is the ranger macro for files held in the copy/cut buffer.

Files are easily added to the buffer with `yy`, to yank, or `ya`, to add to the copy buffer. Similarly, with `dd`, to cut, or `da`, to add to the cut buffer.

See my other [key-mappings here](http://dquinton.github.io/debian-install/config/ranger.html#yk)

Comment: Thanks! I'll take these into account. But one thing that makes me wander the most is the actual purpose of the 'move' command present natively in range? It's not doing anything it seems.

Answer (score 9):

mozerella mentions:

> Files are easily added to the buffer with yy, to yank, or ya, to add to the copy buffer. Similarly, with  dd, to cut, or da, to add to the cut buffer.

I've found the method:

1. **dd** on the directory -- Cut
2. navigate to new directory
3. **pp** -- Paste

applies to directories as well.

Answer (score 0):

Though the first answer is pretty damn good in terms of going over some of the deeper dive portions of the related RC file configurations, its better to just get to the damn point.

Let's say you're trying to copy and paste a directory on a remote server. All you you have to do is make sure you're a root user (if needed, ex: in my case, I just wanted to move my public_html folder containing my website deeper into the /var directory, so I needed to be root) with:

```
sudo su
```

(*enter your credentials)

Then, use Ranger:

```
ranger
```

Select the directory, and type:

```
dd
```

Then, navigate to where you want to paste it, and type:

```
pp
```

Voila, you're done!

Comment: You fault the other answer for not getting to the point, but then you clutter yours with talk about ```sudo su```?